# How to render html file with specific tab-content?

Tags: node.js, express, twitter-bootstrap-3, pug

I'm using bootstrap-ajax combination with data-toggle selections.

Jade Code

```
block content
  .container
    ul.nav.nav-tabs.tabs-up
      li.active
        a(href= '#domains', id='domains_tab', data-toggle='tab', rel='tooltip') Domains
      li
        a(href= '#adddomain', id='adddomain_tab', data-toggle='tab', rel='tooltip') Add Domain
      li
        a(href= '#adduser', id='adduser_tab', data-toggle='tab', rel='tooltip') Add User
```

Also

```
#domains.tab-pane.active.fade.in
#adddomain.tab-pane.fade
#adduser.tab-pane.fade
```

Now with express, I want to render(or without rendering if it is possible) this html with a specific tab-content.
For ex,

```
res.render('dashboard#adddomain');
```

I'dont know how what I need to do, but is there any way to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible using ajax and render the content manually, somethink this...

Node function:

```
app.get('/domains', function(req, res){
    res.send({text: 'Here are many domains'});
});
```

Javascript function:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
   $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          cache: false,
          contentType: 'application/json',
          url: '/domains',
          success: function (domains){
              $('#label').empty();
              $('#label').append(domains); // HERE A LABEL IS UPDATE THROUGH RETURNS NODE.JS ('Here are many domains');
          }
         });
});
```

In each tab selection, you can put a check jquery and do a request though jquery ajax to node, get the return and update the content of a component (label, div, table, ...);